# Piecewise function derivative at the point x = 0

Tags: derivatives, continuity, piecewise-continuity

I can't find the derivative of xsin (pi / x) in this question.
$$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
x \sin \frac{\pi}{x} & x \neq 0\\
0 & x = 0
\end{cases}.
\quad \text{Compute }f'(0).
$$

There must also be a differentiability rule for f '(x) to exist.

How do I solve it?

Comment: This function is not differentiable at $0$.

Comment: Yes I know. But how can I show this?

Comment: See if the limit of $\frac {f(x)-f(0)} x$ through the sequence $\frac 1 {n+\frac 1 2 }$ exists.

Comment: okey thanks buddy, ı try

Answer (score 1):

$$f'(x)=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{h \sin (\pi/h)-0}{h}= \lim_{h \to 0} \sin (\pi/h)=\text{does not exist}.$$

$L=\lim_{x \to 0} \sin(\pi/x)$ does not exist for two sequeces $x_n=\frac{1}{n}$ and $x'_n=\frac{1}{(n+1/2)}$, let $g(x)=\sin(\pi/x)$, then $g(x_n)=0, g(x'_n)=1$ these being different there are two accumulation points. So, the limit $L$ does not exist. Hence, $f(x)$ is not differentiable at $x=0$.